# Handling conditional href links

Tags: php, html

I've got several `<a>` tags with conditional links based on a session variable attached to users after successfully logging in.

Example:

```
<a href="/app/<?php echo $_SESSION['user_role'] ?>/index.php">Index</a>
```

The purpose of this is being able to copy-paste the site's functionality for another userbase without having to refactor links everytime I do so.

My site's structure is something like

```
 /home/
       /app/
           /company1/
           /company2/
```

Each folder contains most of the site's functionality (with the exception of most general files shared by all companies), with variations based on each company. This helps me just copy-paste most of the functionality with minor changes.

My question is, is there a better/more efficient way to handle this, or at least a way to do it without mixing HTML with PHP? I'm unsure if what I'm doing here is good practice at all or if there's any other way to do it better.

Comment: How many companies do you anticipate you'll have to do this for, and how much in common do the sites have that you make for them? What you're doing is fine if you only have a few directories, but if you have more than ~10 it will be difficult to maintain as you grow.

Comment: Currently there's 3 small companies working with the site. Anticipating from 6 to 10 more short-term, maybe more in the future. What you do exactly mean by it being difficult to maintain?.

Comment: Well, if you add new customers by copying/pasting the directory `app/customerX` into `app/customerX+1`, then you'll have multiple copies of the same code. What if you need to roll out a bugfix to all your customers at once? How will you be sure that you didn't miss something? The more mostly-identical subdirectories you have, the harder this task becomes.

Comment: I've thought about this and managed to get by for the most part by having a general model in the base directory shared by all customers, where I put most of the things they all have in common. Though I wanted to get things like views (header, navbar, sidebar, footer) and some particular models and scripts separate from eachother as it's easier for me to work with. I'm certain it's not perfect since as you say, changes I need to apply that happen to be on all customers becomes a bit of a task, but it's not a project so big to the point where this becomes a real issue, honestly.

Comment: My main goal is to try and get implementation of new customers to be as quick and painless as possible without putting technical debt on the line too much.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly a more simple solution, probably not. Mixing HTML and PHP is a pretty normal practice. You could get javascript involved and go crazy with some AJAX post requests to have less PHP in your .html file, but honestly what you have might be the easiest solution. Additionally this will also be more secure since the request is handled before headers are sent.

Cheers man